# Unable to use StencilJS with .net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, stenciljs

I am new to StencilJS and have a compiled custom component that i am trying to use in .Net Core MVC.  I add the JavaScript in my _Layout like the following:

```
<script type="module" src="~/js/customui.esm.js"> and <script nomodule src="~/js/customui.js">
```

I then add my custom component tag

```
<my-buttom></my-button>
```

however nothing ever render to the screen.  inside my component render i have:

```
<host class={'myButtonTheme'}>Test render</host>
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong.  I have the StencilJS configure setup to default for output.

Comment: How does the `~` in your paths get resolved? Do you get an error in your browser's console? Also, maybe just a typo in the question, but your opening tag has `buttom` instead of `button`.

Comment: that would be a typo here as in my app its <my-button></my-button>  the ~ is seen as root or the home folder where the files live.  so by doing the ~/js it will go to the root then to my js folder where i have my JavaScript files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the mistake is that you're using `<host>`. `Host` (capitalized) is a functional component that is exported from `@stencil/core` and you have to use it like

```js
import { Component, Host, h } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({ tag: 'my-button' })
export class MyButton {
  render() {
    return <Host class="myButtonTheme">Test render</Host>;
  }
}
```

`<host></host>` as a tag would be a native HTML element (because custom elements need a dash in the name) but no such element exists in the specification.

Comment: I have made the change to my component and re-ran the build.  I put those into my test MVC app and still doesn't work. with the way i call the files i get a failed to load resource on p-12330e4d.js.  Not sure what that is as it only shows up when i have the customui.js files being loaded.  i changed it to just <script src="~/js/customui.js"> and i get two errors one for p-df05220e.sysmte.js and one saying there is an uncaught in promise error.  at htmlscriptelement.<anonymous>.  Is there an issue with the per-built solution form stencil i am using?

Comment: I must of miss understood how to use the created web components.  I thought it was just taking the few JS files with my naming not the whole folder.  I just tried pulling the whole folder over and it worked.  Why did i need the whole folder vs just the named files?  I must be miss understanding how to use the web components.

Comment: Yup you need the whole folder because by default Stencil lazy-loads components by default. There's a new output target called `dist-custom-elements-bundle` since Stencil 1.9 that you can try (use the `--next` flag of the stencil cli). It'll bundle all your components into one js file.